# change the background of imageview android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to change the background of an `ImageView` and share it on Facebook. To do so, I use :

```
imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images));
```

But when I share, the `ImageView` is shared on its own without the background.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use:

```
setImageResource(R.drawable.images)
```

or

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images))
```